# Conversion de bytes de png a RGBAs

Tags: c#, unity, bitmap, color, rgba

.NET 4.

Recibo el array de bytes de un .PNG.
¿Puedo traducir estos datos en un string/string[] de RGBA/ARGB sin hacer uso de System.Drawing en el proceso?

PD: Googlie, pero no encuentre una solución que no implique el uso de System.Drawing.

(Estoy trabajando en Unity)

Comment: Si pusieras un pedazo del codigo donde tienes problemas sera mas facil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir un `array de byte` a un `string` aplicando un encode en `base 64`

Para eso se usa

[Convert.ToBase64String(Byte[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToBase64String_System_Byte___)

es simple

```
string stringImage = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesImage);
```

Para obtener nuevamente el byte array desde el string usarias `Convert.FromBase64String()`